# Paperclip - get image path without ActiveRecord model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

In a specific view, I am rendering an array of POROs created from a SQL query (this is for performance reasons, having ActiveRecord models here would be a major performance problem).

In that view, I need to display an image uploaded with paperclip, but can't find a way of getting Paperclip to return an image url without an ActiveRecord (attachment) instance. I can get the name of the image from the DB ("image.jpg") and the Model name ("User") as well.

I would need something like url("image.jpg", :user, :thumb).

I could hardcode paths, but I would prefer not to, and let paperclip handle this.

Is this possible?

Thanks,
Ricardo

Comment: see paperclip demo may be helpful for you - http://ruby-on-rails-dipak-panchal.blogspot.in/2012/10/paperclip-sample-app_4.html

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't show how to load attachment url without having a model

Comment: Any update on this?  Run into the same thing myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a gist for that [here](https://gist.github.com/basgys/5712426)

Basically your object needs to implement some ActiveModel modules to fullfil Paperclip requirements, because this library is strongly coupled to ActiveRecord.